# At what size does a picture become unusable for facial recognition?

Tags: computer-vision, image-recognition, facial-recognition

Lets say i have a portrait photo of which the face it contains covers about 90% of the entire photo. I want to be able to detect the face in this photo using facial recognition but i also want to reduce the file size of this photo. The best way to reduce the file size is to make the size dimensions of the photo smaller.

I want to know at what size a face containing photo becomes unusable for facial recognition. For instance could a 25 x 25 pixels photo still be used for facial recognition or would this be too small?

Comment: 25x25 you can barely understand if a it's a child or an adult... have you tried to read some publications and see what res the used?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia but will it still recognize the face?

Comment: if you mean "recognize if there is a face", yes, if you mean "recognize which face is on that image", no (probably)

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia probably isn't going to cut it. I need facts.

Comment: @Maurice You can't really have a definite answer to this question, it will depend on what sort of accuracy you are hoping to obtain.

Comment: @finlaymorrison lets say an accuracy of 90%